# Use one ListData.svc reference to update multiple lists

Tags: web-services, metadata, listdata.svc

Can you use **one ListData.svc** reference to update multiple lists even if the lists have different columns?

Site A - Shared Documents

- Default columns
- Model Year
- Make

Site B - Shared Documents

- Default columns
- Favorite color
- Lucky number

If I create a console app to update the `Title` column of Site A - Shared Documents, then I try to updated Site B - Shared Documents, I'm receiving this error:

> <message xml:lang="en-US">Error processing request stream. The property name 'ModelYear' specified for type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ListNameItem' is not valid.</message>